# Interconnecting autodesk forge and Vault api

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-vault

Currently I'm working on a project where i need to use forge viewer and vault APIs

The system i'm developing should get files from vault and display those in the forge viewer.

I couldn't find any guide or references on how to connect both API's to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vault and Forge are two different APIs. And currently, as I know, we have not integrate Vault file system with Forge services, which means the Vault files cannot be accessed in the role of users (while some other cloud products support such as BIM 360, Fusion 360, because they are built on Forge services as well)

So, you would need to use Vault API to get the files from Vault, and use Forge web service to upload and translate the file, in order to view the model in the Forge Viewer.

I am not sure if you have played with Vault API or Forge API. These are just some materials which might be useful:

1. Using the Vault API and View and Data API Together to Download and View 
   Assemblies
   https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Using-Vault-API-and-View- and-Data-API-Together-Download-and-View-Assemblies-2015
   This was delivered by our colleague in 2015 Autodesk University. At that time, 
   the technology of viewing model in the browser is called View and Data. The 
   basic workflow is similar to current Forge Viewer.
2. Vault APIs tutorials：
    https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/vault
    which contains the materials how to get started with Vault. As to the specific topics on downloading files, you can refer to the handout in the above AU class
3. Forge Viewer tutorials
   https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/
   And I also recommend the other step by step tutorial:
   http://learnforge.autodesk.io/

Should you have any questions in the process, please feel free to pose the questions with autodesk-forge tag.