# Autodesk VAULT access through API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-vault

Looking into retrieving from Autodesk vault information through an API, but cannot find any good documentation to do this.
And when I read this reply ([Interconnecting autodesk forge and Vault api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372850/interconnecting-autodesk-forge-and-vault-api/53474694#53474694)) there is no webservice API, like the forge. But that reply was years ago, so hopefully this is outdated.

I browsed through a lot of Autodesk documentation and github code, but where Forge is pretty well documented I cannot find the same level of documentation for Vault.

Concrete question is how to connect to the Vault through means of an webservice API client?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned Autodesk Platform Services (APS, Formerly Forge) is web services, but Autodesk Vault is actually an "on premise" solution and typically behind a corporate domain/firewall for the customers using it. Your Web app would need to be able to access the Vault in an on-premise scenario.

Depending on the APS services, we have some specific content and samples. Here is the best one for APS Design Automation connection to Vault:

https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Using-Vault-Forge-Design-Automation-Inventor-2020

This idea from Vault perspective could be used for the Vault file access and for custom APS Viewer/Model Derivative workflows if that is what you are needing.

The Vault API documentation is part of the product docs. See here for the latest, but you should be aware of the specific Vault version you are working with to be sure the APIs docs match...

https://help.autodesk.com/view/VAULT/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-F21E7DD6-39E9-473C-84BB-3446BCAFCCC0

Also, we have a Manufacturing blog, which has Vault topics and cross over with APS. I would suggest checking it out for specialized topics. See here:
https://adndevblog.typepad.com/manufacturing/vault/

As you will find, the Vault is Windows based API environment so .NET is typical developer environment. On webservices side, we also support .NET development, so that environment is best for connecting the two. Vault is also tied very closely to Inventor and it's data, so there is overlap. If you need specifics on inventor, there are separate documentation for it's API as well (see here).
https://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-6FD7AA08-1E43-43FC-971B-5F20E56C8846

Note that Inventor also has APS Design Automation engine, which is the AU class topic mentioned above (complete workflow with APS web app, Vault data in Inventor format, and using Inventor DA to Automate Inventor workflows.

Finally, the SDK and samples for both Vault and Inventor have to be installed after the main products are installed, so be sure to do that as needed. There are more detailed help there as well. Here are the SDK install instructions for 2024 releases:
Vault: https://help.autodesk.com/view/VAULT/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-F21E7DD6-39E9-473C-84BB-3446BCAFCCC0
Inventor: https://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-6FD7AA08-1E43-43FC-971B-5F20E56C8846

Comment: thanks for the elaborate answer, i think I generally have an idea of the road to follow now. Since you seem knowledgeable on the subject, do you recommend a flow for the simple activity of retrieving thumbs from part items in vault.
Also is it possible to use the autodesk 3D viewer for offline content.

Comment: There is a posting here that talks about thumbnails from Vault... https://justonesandzeros.typepad.com/blog/2009/09/viewing-thumbnails.html

About using the Viewer for offline content, you can do it, but the Viewer should be served from the Autodesk Platform Services. There is an older Autodesk University class that discusses the idea here: https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Creating-Flexible-Offline-Workflows-Using-Autodesk-Forge-2018